# Tuples as templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, types, tuples, variadic

I get a tuple of types (e.g. std::tuple) and I want to create tuple of vectors given by these types. I wrote this, but when I use it as I want, it doesn't work, I get this error:

```
Error (active)  E0730   type "types" is not a class template
```

I am pretty new to variadic templates so I don't know how to do it properly.

```cpp
using namespace std;

template <template <typename...> typename Tuple, typename... Types>
class vertices
{
public:
    tuple<vector<Types...> > v;
};

int main{
    using types = tuple<int, string, double>;

    vertices<types> ver;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it appears your requirement is just to be able to conveniently express the type

```
tuple<vector<int>, vector<string>, vector<double>>
```

as

```
vertices<tuple<int, string, double>>
```

This can be achieved using a variable template. All we need is to take a type (that's a tuple), and unpack that tuple into a vector. Since a type is not a variadic pack, we need another level of indirection to get the types within the tuple. @NathanOliver's answer shows a nice way to do that, using the declaration of a function-template. As pointed out, since all we need is type transformations, the function doesn't need a definition, the declaration says it all: the argument type is the input type, and the return type is the output type.

```
template <typename... Types>
auto unpack(tuple<Types...>) -> tuple<vector<Types>...> ;

template <typename Tuple>
using vertices = decltype(unpack(declval<Tuple>())); 

static_assert(std::is_same<
                  vertices<tuple<int, string, double>>,
                  tuple<vector<int>, vector<string>, vector<double>>>{});
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `Tuple` is a template template parameter, so it expects a template.  `types` is not a template but a concrete type, so it is not usable.  Instead what you can do is just take in the tuple, and then using a helper meta function get the type for the member like

```
// no definition since it is only used in unevaluated contexts, just used as a helper to get the type converted
template <typename... Types> 
std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...> tuple_to_tuple_of_vectors(std::tuple<Types...>);

template <typename Tuple>
class vertices
{
public:
    using tuple_type = decltype(tuple_to_tuple_of_vectors(std::declval<Tuple>()));
    tuple_type v;
};

int main ()
{
    using types = tuple<int, string, double>;

    vertices<types> ver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first template parameter is a template template parameter, but `types` is not a template, it is a type. Also you have the `...` in the wrong place. You need `tuple<vector<Types>...>`, otherwise `Types` is expanded as parameters for `vector`.

The following comes with a disclaimer: I know a bit of tempaltes with C++11, but I am rather ignorant about newer features, so there might be more elegant ways to write the same.

As base template you can use:

```
template <typename... Types>
struct vertices
{
    using tuple_of_vectors_t = tuple<vector<Types>... >;
    tuple_of_vectors_t v;
};
```

And then for tuples:

```
template <typename... Types>
struct vertices<std::tuple<Types...>> : vertices<Types...> {};
```

Complete example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <typename... Types>
struct vertices
{
    using tuple_of_vectors_t = tuple<vector<Types>... >;
    tuple_of_vectors_t v;
};

template <typename... Types>
struct vertices<std::tuple<Types...>> : vertices<Types...> {};


int main () {
    using types = tuple<int, string, double>;

    vertices<types> ver;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v< vertices<types>::tuple_of_vectors_t, 
                                 std::tuple< std::vector<int>, 
                                             std::vector<std::string>,
                                             std::vector<double>
                                           >
                                >;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```